# Variable to Point to a Vector

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm attempting to make a command line side scrolling shooter. However, I am struggling to get the inheritance and class/struct structure set up for the different ship types. However, there is a fair chance that I am completely misunderstanding how to go about this.

```
class Ship
{
int health;
float charging;
bool charged;
coords location;
bool shielded;
int chargeSpeed;
int cannons;
int shieldHealth;

struct enemyShip
{
    int speed;
    shipType type;
};

struct bossShip
{
    int Bonuspoints;
};

struct myShip
{
    int lives;
    int points;
    int isDead;
};
void createShip(shipType type, int speed, int health, bool shields, int cannons, int chargeSpeed, int bonusPoints)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    speeder:
        Ship::enemyShip newShip;
        newShip.speed = 0;

        ships.push_back(newShip);
    bruiser:
    sprayer:
    boss:

    }
}
};
```

That's the`Ship` class as it stands currently. My idea was that I will be able to pass the parameters to the createShip method (from my gameloop) and that will create a new `Ship` of the correct type and then dump it into the list of ships (which is global).

However, whilst I can easily access the attributes of my `newShip` object that belong to whichever `struct` has been used to create it, in the case shown I can use `newShip.speed` after `newShip = Ship::enemyShip newShip;` to access these. However, I cannot work out how to access all of the attributes that it will have inherited from the parent class; such as `health`, `charging`, etc.

Any help would be appreciated, I have searched, however, most answers simply say `this->x = x::x` or something of that ilk, and I have tried `newShip->health = 100` and that doesn't work. Consequently, either a little more detail would be appreciated or a completely different answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [There is no inheritance here.](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/112-basic-inheritance-in-c/)

Comment: Hang on, so you can't just place structs/classes inside eachother?

Comment: You can put it there it you like, but it won't inherit from the containing class. Have you seen [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191)?

Comment: No I hadn't thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hoist (for example) `enemyShip` out of `Ship` and declare it as:

```
struct enemyShip : Ship
{
    int speed;
    shipType type;
};
```

The `: Ship` says that `enemyShip` derives from `Ship`.

You will then need to define `createShip` outside struct `Ship` (because inside `Ship` `enemyShip` won't be properly defined).

Comment: As @BobTFish implies, I think you need a good C++ book.  You need to be writing header files, and all sorts of stuff that is really too long for an SO answer.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, totally misunderstood all of the inheritance stuff. Thanks for your help!